# how to move files from sub-folder to folder

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, copy-paste, xcopy

I've got:

C:/PICS/ASF/photos/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/DFS/photos/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/HGD/photos/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/FTG/photos/files (.jpg)

.....etc

In every "photos" directory is more than one .jpg file

I want:

C:/PICS/ASF/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/DFS/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/HGD/files (.jpg)

C:/PICS/FTG/files (.jpg)

.....etc

Can someone help me with a .cmd that is doing this job?

Best Regards

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as how to move all at once, but You can try below command

move /Y c:\PICS\ASF\photos*.jpg c:\PICS\ASF\

Note :: you will need to rename folder name in source and destination as below.

move /Y c:\PICS\DFS\photos*.jpg c:\PICS\DFS\

move /Y c:\PICS\HGD\photos*.jpg c:\PICS\HGD\

move /Y c:\PICS\FTG\photos*.jpg c:\PICS\FTG\

Hope this helps.